# what is --ci and --no-ci options in lerna bootstrap

Tags: monorepo, lerna

I found following command in certain `package.json`.I understand `lerna bootstrap` is like `npm install`. but I couldn't figure out what is the `--ci` and `--no-ci` options of that

`lerna bootstrap --ci`

`lerna bootstrap --no-ci`

I read lerna [read.me](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/v2.0.0-beta.32/README.md#flags),but I couldn't find out this kind of options.

Are there any document of that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you do `lerna bootstrap`, it by default runs `npm ci`. If you provide `--no-ci` argument, then it will run `npm install`.

Check [this section](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/main/commands/bootstrap/README.md#--no-ci) of their README for more info.

Comment: no it doesn't...